# Looking for 8x8 (or nxn) Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT)/IDCT Pseudo-Code

Tags: c++, algorithm, dct

I've been searching Google for a while now to find pseudo-code of a decently efficient 8x8 (or nxn) DCT algorithm, and I can't find anything!

I implemented the naive approach, and it took far too long to execute.

If you could post some pseudo-code or reference a good book/document/website, that would be helpful.

C or C++ examples would be better yet!

Comment: That's odd, a quite naive approach runs quite fast here, how long is "too long"?

Comment: I was processing a 512x512 image with 3 channels, and it was taking minutes before I turned it off. Perhaps I implemented it incorrectly or got stuck in an infinite loop somehow. Let me try again.

Comment: I had precomputed the cosine tables of course, but other than that it was just the naive approach of doing it exactly like the definition suggests. But even with those cosines it shouldn't take long.

Comment: Are you using separability? @harold

Comment: I don't know, to be honest I'm not an expert on DCT's - I'm using two nested loops both going from 0 to 8, instead of doing it first in one dimension and then in the other, is that what that means?

Comment: Yes. Could you post your source code? I am trying to do some steganography, and I need a simple dct and idct to hide information in that space. @harold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested in the comments, source (be slightly warned, it's in C#, but the difference with C++ should be minimal, and yes I know the code is lame):

Main loop (A = result, B = input):

```
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        A[y * 8 + x] = 0;
        for (int u = 0; u < 8; u++)
            for (int v = 0; v < 8; v++)
                A[y * 8 + x] += alpha(u) * alpha(v) * B[u, v] *
                    cosine[u, x] * cosine[v, y];
    }
}
```

Support stuff:

```
static double alpha(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
        return SQRT2o2 * 0.5;
    return 0.5;
}
const double SQRT2o2 = 1.414213562373095048801688724209 * 0.5;
cosine = new double[8, 8];
const double inv16 = 1.0 / 16.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
     {
         cosine[j, i] = Math.Cos(Math.PI * j * (2.0 * i + 1) * inv16);
     }
}
```

edit: I timed it - for 512 by 512 pixels (single channel) it takes half a second. Sure that's slow, but nowhere near "forever".

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm not looking for ultra performance.

Comment: @user904963 do you know the changes required to turn it into iDCT? I could post that as well.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

[FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) has an open source efficient implementation